# How to stay in current tab(tabview) on Page reload

Tags: html, css

How can I stay in the current Tab when using tabview when the page is reloaded

Answer (score 1):

Add information about current/opened tag to url.
www.example.pl#contact-tab
after reload check which tab was open and open it again

Comment: By tabview you probably mean YUI element. So it is javascript. When your page is reloaded all js state is lost. You need to keep somewhere information what was the last opened tab before reload. I suggest add this info to url. When you page is reloaded in onload action you can check if url contains info about tab and opened requested tag again.